Is always low bias and low variance desirable?
Assume we have two regression models M1 and M2 for a given data. Assuming M2 has lower bias and lower variance, would you always consider using this? This example shows that if the data is random noise ( I did not try other cases!) if we do we should use the baseline ( constant function equal to data average).
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

# Generate synthetic data
X = np.random.rand(50, 1)
y = 2 * X + np.random.randn(50, 1) * 0.5  # Linear relationship with added noise

# Baseline model: Constant function equal to the average of the target variable
baseline_prediction = np.mean(y)
baseline_predictions = np.full_like(y, fill_value=baseline_prediction)

# Create instances of LinearRegressionWithBiasVariance for both models
baseline_model = LinearRegressionWithBiasVariance()
linear_model = LinearRegressionWithBiasVariance()

# Fit the models
baseline_model.fit(np.ones_like(X) * baseline_prediction, y)
linear_model.fit(X, y)

# Calculate biases and variances
baseline_bias = baseline_model.model_bias(np.ones_like(X) * baseline_prediction, y)
baseline_variance = baseline_model.model_variance(np.ones_like(X) * baseline_prediction)

linear_bias = linear_model.model_bias(X, y)
linear_variance = linear_model.model_variance(X)

using the formulas:

mean_prediction = np.mean(predictions) bias = np.mean(mean_prediction- mean)
variance = np.mean((predictions - np.mean(predictions))**2)

I ran the code and it returned:
-Baseline Model (Constant Function): Bias: 9.547918011776346e-17
-Variance: 4.930380657631324e-32
-Linear Regression Model: Bias: 1.6653345369377348e-16 Variance:
-0.3576954239953287
As we see both bias and variance of the constant function are smaller!
